# How to handle a non-existing file in python

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling

currently doing a Tafe project and in a bit of a rush. how would go about handling not having the files highscore.txt and username.txt. thanks in advance.

my code is below:

```
def hScoreSystem():
    #open username
    with open("username.txt", "r+") as username:
        user = username.read()
    #open score
    with open("highscore.txt", "r+") as highscore:
        hscore = highscore.read()
        if score > int(hscore):
            #saving username
            username.seek(0)  #going back to the start
            username.write(currentName)
            username.truncate()
            #saving highscore
            highscore.seek(0)  # We already read to the end. We need to go back to the start
            highscore.write(str(score))
            highscore.truncate()
            #print highscore title
            displayLine("=", 80, "=")
            print("New Highscore!")
            displayLine("=", 80, "=")
            #print User and Highscore
            print("Username: ", currentName) 
            print("Highscore: ", score)
            displayLine("=", 80, "=")
            #print Current users score
            print("Your Score: ", score)
            displayLine("=", 80, "=")
            print()
        else:
            #print Highscore title
            displayLine("=", 80, "=")
            print("Highscore")
            displayLine("=", 80, "=")
            #print User and Highscore
            print("Username: ", user) 
            print("Highscore: ", hscore)
            displayLine("=", 80, "=")
            #print Current users score
            print("Your Score: ", score)
            displayLine("=", 80, "=")
            print()
```

Comment: Would you like them to be automatically created if they don't exist?

Comment: Please read through the documentation on [file processing](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) to learn more about creating a file if one is empty. Or you can use try-except to catch the error of [file not available](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)

Comment: Read more about [file exception] (https://realpython.com/python-exceptions/) here. Example to use:   
try:
    with open('file.log') as file:
        read_data = file.read()
except FileNotFoundError as fnf_error:
    print(fnf_error)